# Print documents to PDF files via command line in Wine

Tags: windows-command-prompt, microsoft-office-2010, printing, wine

I have a task to use Wine on Linux distributive for work with MS Office files doc[x] / xls[x] / ppt[x] and pdf via virtual printer. Output formats I need are png or jpg. This is for converter of documents and presentations.

I can convert a ps file which is output of MS Office 2010 print into file dialog. I can also user pdf2ps utility. So I need first stage - how to print Office's documents into file via command line with Wine? After this I'll be able to convert ps to image formats, or pdf2ps and to images also.

Please, help to find a solution.

Comment: Evgeniy, you've asked 11 questions in your time on SF, most of which have answers, **none** of which you have accepted.  Local etiquette is that once you're satisfied with an answer to a question, you accept it by clicking the tick outline next to it.  That drives the SF reputation system for both asker and author, and it stops your question floating around forever like a querulous albatross.  It also encourages people to bother answering your newer questions.  You might want to review your existing question base and accept some answers.

Comment: Okay, excuse me. I'll do it.

Comment: Well done you - many thanks.  Hope this question finds an answer; I know nothing about MS software, so can shed no light.

Comment: Update. I know there are commands to print from Word, Excel, Powerpoint utilities to a file (to default system printer). I can exec them via cmd.exe. So, the more concrete problem is - is it possible to exec such commands via cmd via wine console? For example, I want to print a DOCX via cmd. I can do it via `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\WINWORD.EXE /P "C:\Path to\My_file.docx"`. The default printer will be used. Commands for Excel and Powerpoint are similar. I need help with wine variation, because when I try to type these commands - I receive a blue screen of wine.